# polynomial notation confusion regarding degree

Tags: polynomials

Let $p0, p1, ...pn \in P(R)$

For the statement above, do the polynomials $p0, p1...pn$ have to be of the same degree? Or $p0$ has degree $0$ and $p1$ has degree $1$...$pn$ has degree $n$? Or none of the above?

Say if $n = 2$,
does that mean $p0$ is a constant, $p1$ is a linear polynomial and $p2$ is a quadratic polynomial?
Or all of them could be quadratic polynomials?
Or one of them is linear and two of them are quadratic?

Answer (score 0):

All your statement demands is that they are all polynomials.  They could have any degree.  It is fairly common to have $p_0$ be a constant, $p_1$ be linear and so on, but that needs to be spelled out.  If $n=2$ you could have $p_0$ be of tenth degree, $p_1$ be quadratic, and $p_2$ be of fiftieth degree.